# Comparing Date Ranges in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` column like below:

```
0   2013-07-01 13:20:05.072029
1   2013-07-01 15:49:33.110849
2   2013-07-01 13:39:18.608330
Name: invite_sent_time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Now I wanted to create another column `month` where if the date range is between `2013-07-01` and `2013-08-01` then `Jul` else `Aug`

I did something like below:

```
# Creating a column for month. 
invites_combined["month"]=np.where(((invites_combined.invite_sent_time.dt.Date >= pd.Timestamp('2013-07-01')) & \
                                   (invites_combined.invite_sent_time.dt.Date < pd.Timestamp('2013-08-01'))),"July","Aug")
```

But it said can't compare Date with Timestamp. I cannot use the date in quotes directly as it is taken as string.

So where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 5):

You need add `date()` to `Timestamp` for comparing `dates`:

```
dates = invites_combined.invite_sent_time.dt.date
mask = (dates>=pd.Timestamp('2013-07-01').date()) & (dates<pd.Timestamp('2013-08-01').date())
invites_combined["month"] = np.where(mask,"July","Aug")
```

Or [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
mask = invites_combined.invite_sent_time.between('2013-07-01', '2013-08-01')
invites_combined["month"] = np.where(mask ,"July","Aug")
```

But better and more general is use [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
invites_combined["month"] = invites_combined.invite_sent_time.dt.strftime('%b')
```

Sample:

```
print (invites_combined)
            invite_sent_time
0 2013-07-01 13:20:05.072029
1 2013-07-01 15:49:33.110849
2 2013-08-01 13:39:18.608330 <-last date was changed to August

invites_combined["month"] = invites_combined.invite_sent_time.dt.strftime('%b')
print (invites_combined)
            invite_sent_time month
0 2013-07-01 13:20:05.072029   Jul
1 2013-07-01 15:49:33.110849   Jul
2 2013-08-01 13:39:18.608330   Aug
```